# How do I add PostGIS to my PostgreSQL setup using pure docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis

We have been using the following `docker-compose.yml` to account for PostgreSQL (another other redacted) dependencies.

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres132:
    image: postgres:13.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'user'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'pass'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'db'
    volumes:
        - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

Now, I need to add PostGIS support to the same container. Is that possible and how can I do that? I'm new to both Postgres and PostGIS so forgive my ignorance about the same.

Comment: have you tried this image? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/445#issuecomment-638467374

Comment: @JimJones I don't think that's an official distribution and I'd like to stick with official distributions only if I can.

Comment: It's not ideal to store passwords in environment variables - If anything else is/was running in the same container, it could read the value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not use Dockerfile specfic to add postgis?

Change your "image" property to "build" property to link a Dockerfile.

Your docker-compose.yml would look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Then create a text file named `Dockerfile-db` in the same path as docker-compose.yml with the following content:

```
FROM postgres:14.1


RUN apt-get update && apt-get  install -y postgresql-14-postgis-3  


CMD ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh","postgres"]
```

notice that you can specify the PostGIS version that goes along with your Postgresql version.

This way you can install all you need in the container by extending the `Dockerfile-db`

Notice: your db container now has PostGIS but we need to create the extension in  the DB and for that you should run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
you only need to do this once if you use volumes.

Bonus: One way of doing it's by preparing a directory called db/ with init.sql file and write something like `CREATE EXTENSION postgis ;` and persist it as a volume in docker compose so the final format for your docker-compose would be :

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: db_name
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - database_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  database_volume:
```

this way the postgresql will run this script and create your extensions

Comment: Thanks! seeing that all real usages include having to maintain persistent data between reboots, can you include the volume part in this compose yaml for storing the db data persistently?

Comment: yeah you can achieve that through volume binding i edited the yaml

Comment: @Ayush, this shall be the accepted answer.

Comment: In my case for postgres:15.5 the folder PostgreSQl/16 is created, and I use `RUN apt-get update && apt-get  install -y postgresql-16-postgis-3` instead of `postgresql-15-postgis-3`

Answer (score 7):

https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis

Why not use the PostGIS image at the above link which is based on the official PostgreSQL image?

Comment: Because while today I might need PostGIS, I might need other extensions in the future given the roadmap, and I'd like to not visit this problem again if I can find a generic solution.

Comment: So using the  default PostgreSQL image add your customisation somewhere like the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.
[https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)  Look at the documentation, particularly the sections Initialisation Scripts and Additional Extensions.

Comment: For example, PostGIS is now lagging behind Postgres in CPU architecture compatibility. arm64 is currently still not supported for postgis' image.